# module object has no attribute after using different version of Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both versions python 2.7 and 3.4 installed. I am using some code which is developed under 2.7 but I am using under 3.4. So after compiling using the following command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error -

```
  File "C:\pyprojects\focus\site\general\forms.py", line 26, in Meta
    model = models.UserProfile
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'
```

The directory structure is

```
├───focus
│   ├───data_dumps
│   ├───notes
│   ├───setup
│   └───site(main project folder)
|       └───static
|       └───general
|           +--forms.py
|           +--models.py
|       └───pro
|           └───models
|               +--__init__.py
|               +--plans.py
│       └───focus2
│           └───templates
|           +--__init__.py
│           +--settings.py
│           +--util.py            
│           +--wsgi.py
│       +--manage.py
```

As models.py and forms.py is under same directory(general) so I have imported the model in forms.py in this way

```
from .models import models
```

Now in models.py I have defined the class

```
class UserProfile(models.Model, HashedPk):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
        is_pro = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
        ......................................................
```

In forms.py the code is

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        .....................
```

Is there any special way to call the model in python 3.4.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you using same django version with python2 and python3?

Comment: Yes I am using the same django version which is 1.10

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted. The import needs to be

```
from . import models
```

instead

```
from .models import models
```